# How to fit large frequency table into R markdown ioslides?

Tags: r, r-markdown, ioslides

I'm trying to fit large table of frequencies into my slide. There are many values, and even the rare ones would be nice to show.

I played with different options but none gives me a satisfactory solution. Here is `Rmd` so far:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "author"
date: "date"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
df <- as.data.frame(table(rownames((USArrests))))
```

## table 1

```{r t1, echo = TRUE}
table(rownames((USArrests)))
```

## table 2

```{r t2}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
kable(df, "html") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", font_size = 10)
```
````

Table 1 doesn't fit:

[image]

Table 2 could be squeezed but with tiny font, and lots of wasted space on the sides.

I also looked into `pander`, `xtable` and `stargazer` but failed to find solution from them either.

Any other alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could spread your table across multiple columns to fit the space. In my example below, I split the frame up into 3 pairs of columns with uneven length.

````
---
output: ioslides_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
```

## table 1

```{r, echo=TRUE, eval=FALSE}
USArrests %>% rownames %>% table
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
df <- USArrests %>%
  rownames %>%
  table %>%
  as_tibble

df %$%
  tibble(
    name1 = `.`[1:17],
    n1 = n[1:17],
    name2 = `.`[18:34],
    n2 = n[18:34],
    name3 = c(`.`[35:50], ""),
    n3 = c(n[35:50], "")
  ) %>%
  kable("html", align = c("l", "c"), col.names = rep(c("Name", "Frequency"), 3)) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "condensed"), font_size = 18)
```
````

[image]

> **N.B.** I accept the transform step into multiple columns could have been done more elegantly and providing and more programmatic solution, however, I'll leave that to others to refine.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin - does the job.